# OAuth2 Login for Google Calendar API

Tags: api, calendar, google-oauth

I'm making a website for a football club. they have one google calender (and just one google account). on the website I'd like to have a list of upcoming events. So I've to access to Google Calendar via Google API. For Authorisation I've to use OAuth2.  Is it possible to login with OAuth2 automatically so that the website visitors don't have login always via redirect (to google login site)? For example I make a the login via Java, instead of a user login? Because it's no so comfortable if every user of the website have to login, for just viewing the club calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it is possible,

Important note concerning your design: if you login automatically to the club's account, it means that everyone that uses this website is logged in to Google Calendar on behalf of the club's user name. hence, everyone can CHANGE the calendar, delete events, etc.

Are you sure you want this to happen?

(you can set the login params to "read-only", but even then, it means that the club shows ALL his calendar to everyone. there is no privacy...)

**I suggest that every user logins *with his own creds*, and the club's calendar can invite all registered users to his events....**

Comment: if he does the login stuff on server side, he can filter and restrict the generated html output

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can do it, and even without giving the access to the visitor if you're doing this on the server side.

You need to do a initial step by hand.
After this step you get a **refresh token**, with this token you can regenerate the **access token** which you need to access to the calendar API, for instance to get the upcoming events.
You need to regenerate the **access token** if the previous **access token** is expired. In this case you also get an new **refresh token**. You need to save it, into a database or JSON file.

To get a refresh token you need to pass this options on authorization:

```
access_type: "offline"
approval_prompt: "force"
```

Without these options you only get an access token, no refresh token.

Here is the documentation: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl

And here a kind of tutorial: http://www.tqis.com/eloquency/googlecalendar.htm